# While receiving mail it show "admin@gmail.com" in from box,but it should show "from@gmail.com"

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

Sample Code: I need functionality for send to your friend...

```
NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("admin@gmail.com", "password");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress("mailto@gmail.com");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = loginInfo;

MailAddress from = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

message.Subject = "demo";
message.Body = @"msgBody";

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: use `from@gmail.com` as `NetworkCredential` username

Comment: Allowing this would be a very bad idea for gmail's smtp server. You can use your own smtp server, but expect to be categorized as spam, by DKIM or SPF.

Comment: @ Chamika Sandamal:I cnt because I'll only have two email addresses one To and other is From..for example please visit this URL:http://www.coordit.com.au/ and click email this page to your friend...you only provide two email addresses..and its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasion is are you using smtp of Gmail. 
it would happend due to security issule like... you are using gmail address and send email as xyz@microsoft.com its may create issue....

thats reasion its not allow by gmail.

it may work with your own domain.

Comment: :if you can provide any example please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
message.Headers.Add("From", "From Name <from@gmail.com>");
```